# Clear specific part of ncurses screen c++

Tags: c++, ncurses

I know `clrtoeol()` can clear the entire line however I want to clear the screen from (y0, x0) to (y0, x1).

For example I have a code something like this:

```
mvprintw(6, 22, "Press any key to continue...");
getch();
//and here I want to print another line at the same place and this line is shorter.
mvprintw(6, 22, "shorter line");
```

If I try to print a string(or a character array I think) that is longer then it is fine but when I print a shorter one then the part of the first sentence is still seen.
If I use `clrtoeol();` the entire line is cleared however I have some things at the end of that line which I don't want to be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this after the `getch()` call:

```
move(6, 22);
clrtoeol();
```

ncurses will optimize this so that it will write the (shorter) text-string and then clear the remainder of the line (assuming that you do not add another `refresh` call, or functions such as `getch` which cause a *refresh*).